# Unknown UTM campaign name using facebook pixel

Tags: facebook-analytics

I'm running ads on Facebook with additional URL parameters:

```
source={{site_source_name}}&placement={{placement}}&ad_id={{ad.id}}&adset_id={{adset.id}}&campaign_id={{campaign.id}}&ad_name={{ad.name}}&adset_name={{adset.name}}&campaign_name={{campaign.name}}
```

I've checked the preview Url and it seems that the values are filled properly. 
However, I don't see any data about the ads source/campaign/ad on my pixel analytics page, everything is classified as unknown.

what am I missing?
  Maybe the parameters of Facebook analytics are different from the above?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the URL params are named differently, i.e. `utm_source=X&utm_medium=Y&utm_campaign=Z&utm_content=W`